# How to resolve interned vars within a let?

Tags: clojure

The following code compiles fine:

```
(intern *ns* 'a 1) ;#'user/a
(intern *ns* 'b (+ a 1)) ;#'user/b
```

It also compiles in a `do`:

```
(do
  (intern *ns* 'c 1)
  (intern *ns* 'd (+ c 1)))
```

However compilation fails in a `let` (or any other binding form I have tried, including `fn`):

```
(let []
  (intern *ns* 'e 1)
  (intern *ns* 'f (+ e 1)))
;CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ‘e in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:5)
```

It looks like the interns are not performed in this case until after the `let` completes. My only work around instead of using locals is to mutate atoms or use `alter-var-root`.

Why doesn't `intern` work inside `let`, et al. the same way it does in `do`? Is there a way to force the intern to complete inside a let so that the above example compiles? (BTW, macros are not an option as I want to access runtime information in my binding form using `ns-map`)

Comment: A good question, but the only surprising thing here is that the naked `do` compiles. The contract of the implicit `do` is to execute sequentially, not to compile sequentially. Solution is to `declare` in advance.

Comment: @A.Webb When at the top level, `(do x y z)` compiles x, runs x; compiles y, runs y; compiles z, runs z. This is necessary in order to allow macros to emit multiple forms wrapped in a `do` and have them treated as independent top-level expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write that, because only `do` gets the special treatment causing its subforms to each be compiled and evaluated in order, rather than all compiled at once and then all evaluated. But really, this is a weird way to do what you are trying to do: these manual calls to `intern` are quite unusual. Why not simply put locals into your `let`, and then intern whichever ones you want to keep? `let` has exactly the property you need, in that previously-defined symbols are visible in the next binding.

```
(let [e 1, f (+ e 1)]
  (intern *ns* 'e e)
  (intern *ns* 'f f))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another answer by @amalloy answers the "why" part of the question and suggests a workaround. If, for some reason, it is still important to refer to a value of an interned var, `resolve` function can be used:

```
 (let []
   (intern *ns* 'e 1)
   (intern *ns* 'f (+ @(resolve 'e) 1)))
 ;; => #'user/f
 e
 ;; => 1
 f
 ;; => 2
```